# How to download multiple pictures, on Android, from internal storage in one function to put them into a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, internal-storage

I have such a function:

```
     fun getPhotos(filePath: List<String>): List<Bitmap>
{
}
```

How should I download all the bitmaps without memory and performance issues? Is just using a Glide function in a loop for each String from the filePath list a good idea?

Comment: Do *not* use `List<Bitmap>`. From a memory standpoint, that would be the worst thing you could do. Have your `RecyclerView.Adapter` take the `List<String>`. It can pass the `String` to the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, and the viewholder can use Glide to populate the `ImageView` (or whatever) with the image.